# urbanairship basic Authorization found in Mobile Application Outgoing Traffic

Tags: android, api, authorization, burp-suite

I was testing an android application using Burp suite. When I opened the android application, an app "Outgoing Traffic" log was added in Burp suite Site map. The API request is:

```
PUT /api/channels/<channel-id> HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;
User-Agent: com.test.app (Custom; 5.1; UrbanAirshipLib-android/9.5.2; W_Ps1DDsQAypC5_UuKOeyg; en_US)
Authorization: Basic <auth-key>
Host: device-api.urbanairship.com
Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 227

{"channel":{"device_type":"android","opt_in":false,"locale_country":"US","locale_language":"en","background":false,"tags":[],"set_tags":true,"timezone":"America\/New_York"},"identity_hints":{"user_id":"<user-id>"}}
```

The request has `Authorization: Basic <auth-key>` header while I opened the app ( Without any login). Is it fine to have a public `Authorization` key, because it's returning this response below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 10 Mar 2021 13:21:16 GMT
Location: https://device-api.urbanairship.com/api/channels/<changel-id>
Content-Type: application/vnd.urbanairship+json;version=3
Content-Length: 63
Via: 1.1 google
Alt-Svc: clear
Connection: close

{"ok":true,"channel_id":"<changel-id>"}
```

I found another `GET` endpoint of this when I tried to visit via Browser. It showed basic auth for login but when I used the `Authorization` token, it returned pieces of information to me. So, I am a bit confused about this request. Can anyone elaborate on this?

Answer (score 1):

Using a hardcoded/shared keys for use cases like this is definitely not the correct approach. Are you sure the client didn't make a client auth request before this?

If it is indeed shared/hardcoded keys, what are the risks of doing so?
Well, that depends on the scope of that key. If the key can only share the public information, you probably are not losing a lot. If the key can be used to fetch private/personal data, then that is absolutely dangerous.

The ideal solution would be to use public/unauthenticated endpoints for public data if you want to avoid having users to log in.

Comment: Hey, I am sure that the client didn't make any auth requests, and thank you for your comment.

Comment: @RudraSarkar then this definitely is a lazy way of doing things.